# Filtrar un dato en un campo SQL

Tags: oracle

Tengo esta consulta

```
"SELECT * FROM KTMOVIMIENTOCONTABLE WHERE CM1_TERCERO LIKE '%" + TBNit.Text + "' AND CM1_TIPO = '" + comboBoxTipo.Text + "' AND CM1_NUM LIKE '%" + TBCausacion.Text + "'"
```

la uso para traer unos datos pero cada usuario tiene muchas cuentas "CM1_CUENTA" necesito saber si entre todas las cuentas hay alguna que tenga el 2365 o 53152001 si trae una cuenta con 2365 hace algo y si trae 53152001 hace otra cosa

Comment: como se llama la columna que tiene el dato 2365 ?

Comment: se llama CM1_CUENTA

Comment: ya tendrias que hacer un procedimiento almacenado para los nuevos cambias que solicitas, y los datos los manipulas a traves de una aplicación me imagino... no entiendo bien tu nuevo requerimiento....

Comment: depende de que quieras hacer cuando encuentres los valores que dices, si solo quisieras devolver un mensaje podrías seguir utiliza tu consulta con case when anidados en el select pero si es algo mas complicado como un cálculo u otra operación la lógica cambiaría.

Comment: solo es que si existe la cuenta 2365 entre todas las cuentas que me trae me pase un valor a un textbox

Comment: cuando hablas de textbox entiendo que hablas a nivel de aplicación? de ser así tu consulta seria distinta...

Comment: Puede ser un ciclo para recorrer los campos de CM1_CUENTA y ve si existe la cuenta 2365, pero no se como hacer la consulta SQL

Comment: Si los encuentra, puedes hacer que los registre en una tabla nueva... con un procedimiento almacenado puedes hacer eso.

Comment: Solo necesito saber si existe

Comment: con el query de abajo sabes si existen datos con la característica que solicitas o no? luego ya  a nivel de aplicación manipulas el dato como quieras....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Por lo que entendi, necesitas que tu consulta filtre por el campo `CM1_CUENTA` los cuales contengan en su dato `2365`..

Con un [`like`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B13789_01/server.101/b10759/conditions016.htm) puedes filtrar el resultado de tu búsqueda:

```
SELECT * 
FROM KTMOVIMIENTOCONTABLE 
WHERE CM1_TERCERO LIKE '%" + TBNit.Text + "' 
AND CM1_TIPO = '" + comboBoxTipo.Text + "' 
AND CM1_NUM LIKE '%" + TBCausacion.Text + "'
AND CM1_CUENTA LIKE '2365%' OR CM1_CUENTA LIKE '%53152001%'
```

Si el dato contiene '2365' en el comienzo de su cuerpo, te los mostrara...

Comment: si me sirve pero se me presento otro problema

Comment: ok, si la respuesta fue de su ayuda, no olvide marcar ;) si puedo ayudarte en otra cosas estamos para eso. saludos.

Comment: si pero me genero otro problema lo especifico en la pregunta